# Custom Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a progress bar via simple html/css.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7zjbzh8r/

When i click on voting icon link

```
Voting links
<span class='t1'><a class='vote'id='1' href='javascript:void(0);'></a></span>
.
.
.
```

It will add first check the first progress link anchor tag to find class selected, if not find then add class selected or vise versa

```
//progress  <span class='p1'><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='1' class='pg'></a></span>
```

I have ten 11 voting link and 11 progress links, user can vote in any order but progress link should add class gradually, checking that previoulsy link has class selected or not.

Below is code what i tried to achieve this but could succeed.

```
$(".vote").click(function(){

  $('.pg').each(function(i) {
    if($('.pg').hasClass('selected')){
    //$('.pg').addClass('selected');
    $('.pg').next().addClass('selected');
    }
  });

  event.stopPropagation();


});
```

Comment: here is http://jsfiddle.net/7zjbzh8r/

Comment: this js fiddle is kind of useless! no jquery selected and just added some source whithout any function... no need for fiddle if you just post it like this!

Comment: why r u so harsh, i need help thats why i posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a tally of what has been clicked so far, and what hasn't, in a variable outside the scope of the current event handler.
It doesn't have to be in the global scope, as in the example below..... as long as it's outside the event handler.

The rest is plain and simple logic.

### **[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0svchrv/2/)**

Here is the generously commented code:

```
//the keeper of the tally
var done = [];

//the event handler
$(".vote").click(function (ev) {
    //stop propagating the event
    ev.stopPropagation();

    //alias $(this)
    var self = $(this),
        //get the index of the clicked element,
        //used parent() here because parent element gives us
        //the real index
        idx = self.parent().index();
    //check tally is not already populated
    if(typeof done[idx] == 'undefined'){
        //push any value into the index(th) position of the tally
        //so that the next click does not run this again
        done[idx] = 1;
    
        //work out selected element in the progress links
        var selected = $('.pg.selected'),
            //and the one that should be selected next
            next = selected.parent().next('.p1').find('.pg');
    
        //if nothing was selected previously
        if(!selected.length){
            //the first progress element is next to be selected
            next = $('.pg:eq(0)');
        }
        //apply the desired classes
        self.addClass('selected');
        next.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this in a loop, you have to set this of in 1 go, with the use of a timer. I select all not `.selected` `.pg`s, and use the index `i` to offset them with 100ms (in this case)

```
$('.pg:not(.selected)').each(function(i){
    $elem = $(this);
    setTimeout(
        function(){ $elem.addClass('selected') },
        i*100
        );
});
```

Comment: Hi, i am saying in one go, whenever user clicks on voting link, add class to progress link, one by one, on one click class added to progress and so on. no set timeout is required

Comment: If I click star 4 of 5, and 1&2 where selected, what will happen?

Comment: I have 11 voting link and 11 progress links, iF I click on 1st link then add class to first progress link, then if i click 3rd link than add class to second progress link, i can randomly click any voting link but add class to progress link graudatally. One click add selected class to progress link

Comment: Only the previous one, or if I click the 5th, 1 to 4 will all go?

Answer (score 0):

This will get check if the previous 'Progres' has the class set before adding to the next one, matching the Vote link pressed.

So Vote1 only sets Progres1 if none other are set.
Vote3 only sets Progres3 if Progres2 is set.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b0svchrv/1/)

```
$(".vote").click(function () {
    var curID;    
    curID = $(this).attr('id');
    curID = Number(curID);
    $('.pg').each(function (i) {
        if ( curID === 1 && !$('.pg').hasClass('selected') ) {
            $('[id=' + (curID) + '].pg').addClass('selected');
        }
        if ( $('[id=' + (curID - 1) + '].pg').hasClass('selected') ) {
            $('.pg').removeClass('selected');
            $('[id=' + (curID) + '].pg').addClass('selected');
        }
    });
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```